# Changing views in 2.8 jumps out of ortho

Tags: orthographic

I work mostly in ortho mode but after I switch to side, top, left, right or bottom view, and then move around the view changes to perspective. How can I ensure that it always stays in ortho view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to deactivate *Auto Perspective* in *Preferences* > *Navigation* > *Orbit & Pa*n.

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks!